# wsdl to empty server implementation?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, testing, wsdl

I have a WSDL from a webservice for which I don't have the implementation.

In order to create a client app, I'd like to build a dummy implementation of this WSDL.

Is there any way to create either a WCF service from this WSDL or a oldschool web service ?

I only want the skeleton of the service (throw new NotImplementedException() is ok). Then I will implement a custom test behavior.

ths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For WCF, you can actually do this for the most part. Just use svcutil.exe (or the VS Add Service Reference wizard) to add a reference to the service.

This will generate all data and service contracts, and then all you need to do is add a new class to your project that implements the service contract interface that svcutil generated (which is just a few clicks in VS).